# Filtering and assigning values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Date    Student    Subject    Score
10/1    Luke       English    65
10/1    Alex       English    75     
10/2    Luke       Maths      50     
10/3    Lily       Maths      45     
10/3    Alex       Maths      90     
10/4    Lily       English    60     
10/5    Alex       English    70     
10/6    Luke       English    55     
10/6    Luke       Maths      65     
10/7    Lily       Maths      80     
10/8    Alex       Maths      75     
10/8    Lily       English    90
```

I am trying to accomplish two tasks here, and the output should be three new columns in the dataframe:

```
1. Date of last/next test:
```

For each row, I want to look at the date for the next test for the SAME STUDENT AND SUBJECT. For example, 'next test date' for rows 1 and 2 should be '10/6' and '10/5' respectively.

Similarly, for the last row, 'previous test date' should have a value of '10/4'.

```
2. Change in score:
```

For this column, I am hoping to return the change in score based off the student's last test in the subject. For example, the values for rows 6-8 should be 'nan','-5' and '-10'.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `shift` to solve your problems like below. Use `fillna()` to replace `Nan` values.

**Problem-1**: Find last and next test date:

```
In [941]: df['next_test_dt'] = df.groupby(['Student','Subject'])['Date'].shift(-1).fillna(df['Date'])

In [943]: df['last_test_dt'] = df.groupby(['Student','Subject'])['Date'].shift(1).fillna(df['Date'])

In [944]: df
Out[944]: 
    Date Student  Subject  Score next_test_dt last_test_dt
0   10/1    Luke  English     65         10/6         10/1
1   10/1    Alex  English     75         10/5         10/1
2   10/2    Luke    Maths     50         10/6         10/2
3   10/3    Lily    Maths     45         10/7         10/3
4   10/3    Alex    Maths     90         10/8         10/3
5   10/4    Lily  English     60         10/8         10/4
6   10/5    Alex  English     70         10/5         10/1
7   10/6    Luke  English     55         10/6         10/1
8   10/6    Luke    Maths     65         10/6         10/2
9   10/7    Lily    Maths     80         10/7         10/3
10  10/8    Alex    Maths     75         10/8         10/3
11  10/8    Lily  English     90         10/8         10/4
```

**Problem-2**: Find score difference from the last test score:

```
In [954]: df['score_diff'] = df['Score'] - df.groupby(['Student','Subject'])['Score'].shift(1)

In [957]: df
Out[957]: 
    Date Student  Subject  Score next_test_dt last_test_dt  score_diff
0   10/1    Luke  English     65         10/6         10/1         NaN
1   10/1    Alex  English     75         10/5         10/1         NaN
2   10/2    Luke    Maths     50         10/6         10/2         NaN
3   10/3    Lily    Maths     45         10/7         10/3         NaN
4   10/3    Alex    Maths     90         10/8         10/3         NaN
5   10/4    Lily  English     60         10/8         10/4         NaN
6   10/5    Alex  English     70         10/5         10/1        -5.0
7   10/6    Luke  English     55         10/6         10/1       -10.0
8   10/6    Luke    Maths     65         10/6         10/2        15.0
9   10/7    Lily    Maths     80         10/7         10/3        35.0
10  10/8    Alex    Maths     75         10/8         10/3       -15.0
11  10/8    Lily  English     90         10/8         10/4        30.0
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184460/discussion-between-mayank-porwal-and-adrian-y).